# Physical Applications of Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm writing an essay about Physical Applications of Complex Analysis.

Which ones do you think are more interesting and appropriate for an undergraduate-level course?

All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Contour integrals are pretty important when you're working with signal processing. They're also used extensively when working with things like propagators in the path-integral formulation of quantum mechanics or correlation functions in statistical mechanics. They allow you to easily work with Fourier transforms. In fact, most of the applications of complex analysis in physics are applications of contour integration.

Answer (score -1):

Quantum mechanics

Electronics

Solving integrals for Quantum field theory